# Understanding how Node.js loads a page

Tags: node.js

So I'm learning node.js and I can successfully have it route to a new HTML page and display basic text. However, when I try to add any other javascripts, CSS, or even images, it appearently treats them like its loading a whole HTML file.

The code would be too long to really post so I'll share my console.log output:

> - request for /start received.
> - About to route a request for /start
> - Request handler "start" was called.
> - request for /socket.io/lib/socket.io.js received.
> - About to route a request for /socket.io/lib/socket.io.js
> - No request handler found for /socket.io/lib/socket.io.js
> - request for /style.css received.
> - About to route a request for /style.css
> - No request handler found for /style.css
> - request for /test.jpg received.
> - About to route a request for /test.jpg
> - No request handler found for /test.jpg
> - request for /favicon.ico received.
> - About to route a request for /favicon.ico
> - No request handler found for /favicon.ico

I understand the whole `favicon.ico` mess but I dont know why it treats the other files the way it does.

What do I need to do/consider when loading pages with Node.js?

Comment: Your question is completely unanswerable because this has absolutely nothing with Node.js, and everything to do with whatever framework you are using on top of Node.js to handle HTTP requests.  What are you using?  Express?  Your own code?  It also isn't clear to me what the question is.

Comment: I'm not using Express at this point. After looking at it further this is my theory: when I do `fs.readFile` and read index.html, it goes through and notices links to my CSS or JS files. It then reads those and since the `Content-Type:` is set to `text/html` it does not read those files properly. Therefore not displaying it. It would have to be `text/css` or something.

Comment: You should definitely add a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @JDillon522, If you're doing `fs.readFile` it's up to you to set the content type.  How would Express know what to set?  It's just setting `text/html` because you didn't specify anything.  It's just software... it's not capable of reading your mind.  If you use the built-in static handler, it is aware of many content types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that node.js isn't a web server which serves files in a webroot directory by default. It is a low level application  which has an API to serve network and http requests. While express.js exposes a public folder where you can put your resources, it fetches the files and replies to the requests using roughly the same approach you have mentioned.

Node.js isn't exactly optimized to handle serve files on HTTP. What most people do on production is install a reverse proxy (nginx is a popular choice) so route requests. You can instruct nginx to simply serve the file if found in the web root, otherwise redirect requests to node.js.

Comment: Ouch. I have a lot to learn. Thanks for the good input though

Comment: @JDillon522 no problem. It isn't much to learn as such. Setting up nginx as a reverse proxy for node is like a standard setup these days, so a google search will show you several helpful results. Apart fro that, you just have to remember that node is a low level application. I'd say there are lesser things to learn and remember than ruby on rails, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for those who are rather uninitiated as I am, here is one way to display most common file types *without* using Express.

```
    var file_path = "";
    var mimes = {
        'css':  'text/css',
        'js':   'text/javascript',
        'htm':  'text/html',
        'html': 'text/html',
        'png': 'image/png',
        'jpg': 'image/jpg',
        'jpeg': 'image/jpeg'
    };

    // parses the url request for a file and pulls the pathname
    var url_request = url.parse(request.url).pathname;      
    // finds the placement of '.' to determine the extension                
    var tmp  = url_request.lastIndexOf(".");
    // determines the extension by uing .substring that takes everything after '.'
    var extension  = url_request.substring((tmp + 1));

    //set path of static pages
    if (extension === 'css' || extension === 'js' || extension === 'htm' || extension === 'html' || extension === 'png' || extension === 'jpg' || extension === 'jpeg'){
        file_path = url_request.replace("/", "");
    }

    //load needed pages and static files
    fs.readFile(file_path, function (error, data){
        if(error){
            response.writeHeader(500, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
            response.write("<h1>FS READ FILE ERROR: Internal Server Error!</h1>");    
        }
        else{
            response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": mimes[extension]});  
            response.write(data);
        }

        response.end();  
    });
```

I would love to know of a more succinct way of doing this without using Express.